# Property-based testing and float equality

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

So I'm [trying to compare two implementations](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/9876#issuecomment-485013973) of a function with [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io) to determine if they work the same way with a huge variety of different inputs that I might not think of myself.

I tried using `numpy.testing.assert_allclose` to compare the outputs, but Hypothesis just repeatedly outsmarts it. The more I widen the acceptable tolerance, the larger values Hypothesis throws at it until it fails, even though the outputs are similar enough to be considered the same.

```
E   Not equal to tolerance rtol=0.1, atol=0.001
...
Falsifying example: test_resample_1d_consistency(a=array([7.696582e+12, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00], dtype=float32), num=11)
```

```
E   Not equal to tolerance rtol=0.1, atol=0.01
...
Falsifying example: test_resample_1d_consistency(a=array([7.366831e+13, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00], dtype=float32), num=11)
```

```
E   Not equal to tolerance rtol=1000, atol=1000
...
Falsifying example: test_resample_1d_consistency(a=array([8.360933e+18, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00], dtype=float32), num=186)
```

etc.

So I guess I need a different "good enough" test of similarity, or I need to limit the input value range in some way?  But I'm not sure how to do these in a way that won't miss genuinely wrong answers. Any advice?

Comment: As you know, it is better to put mcve instead of link to github and statement “I tried using numpy and Hypothesis”.

Comment: @Sanyash I don't understand your comment.  What is mvce?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Sanyash That's not applicable to this type of question

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `rfft` does give very different results in extreme cases - so you'll need to decide whether this is a bug or not.  Maybe Hypothesis has actually shown that it's not a suitable optimization!

Put another way, the problem of determining an appropriate error tolerance for a given magnitude of input is actually the hardest part of testing!  (in the literature, this is "the oracle problem" of how to distinguish good from bad behavior)

Once you have a bound though - say `rtol=0.1, atol=0.001` for all arrays with elements in `[-1000., 1000.]` you can pass the `elements` argument to the `arrays` strategy to constrain those values for each test, or try a range of magnitude/tolerance combinations.

Comment: `the problem of determining an appropriate error tolerance for a given magnitude of input is actually the hardest part of testing!` Yes, that's why I couldn't figure it out on my own and asked an SO question about how to decide it! :D